# How to test a value on being AnyVal?

Tags: scala

Tried this:

```
scala> 2.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
<console>:8: error: type AnyVal cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceOf test
              2.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
                            ^
```

and this:

```
scala> 12312 match {
     | case _: AnyVal => true
     | case _ => false
     | }
<console>:9: error: type AnyVal cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceOf test
              case _: AnyVal => true
                      ^
```

The message is very informative. I get that I can't use it, but what should I do?

Comment: Useful reads: [Scala Type Hierarchy](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) and [Pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you want to test if something is a primitive value:

```
def testAnyVal[T](x: T)(implicit evidence: T <:< AnyVal = null) = evidence != null

println(testAnyVal(1))                    // true
println(testAnyVal("Hallo"))              // false
println(testAnyVal(true))                 // true
println(testAnyVal(Boolean.box(true)))    // false
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to use the `null` trick: `def testAnyVal[T](x: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = m <:< manifest[AnyVal]`.

Comment: @TravisBrown - Or if you don't want to write an explicit manifest parameter, `def testAnyVal[T: Manifest](t: T) = manifest[T] <:< manifest[AnyVal]`

Comment: @Rex: Right, that's nicer—I was just sticking more closely to Thipor's formulation.

Answer (score 14):

I assume that your type is actually `Any` or you'd already know whether it was `AnyVal` or not.  Unfortunately, when your type is `Any`, you have to test all the primitive types separately (I have chosen the variable names here to match the internal JVM designations for the primitive types):

```
(2: Any) match {
  case u: Unit => println("Unit")
  case z: Boolean => println("Z")
  case b: Byte => println("B")
  case c: Char => println("C")
  case s: Short => println("S")
  case i: Int => println("I")
  case j: Long => println("J")
  case f: Float => println("F")
  case d: Double => println("D")
  case l: AnyRef => println("L")
}
```

This works, prints `I`, and does not give an incomplete match error.