# Why can AnyVal not be used in an isInstanceOf check?

Tags: scala

I was wondering, why AnyVal can not be used in an isInstanceOf check ?
What is the reason behind this behavior ?

```
scala> val c = 't'
c: Char = t

scala> c.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
<console>:12: error: type AnyVal cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceO
f test
             c.isInstanceOf[AnyVal]
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416658

Comment: I guess, this is related too http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3271

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test a value on being AnyVal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416658/how-to-test-a-value-on-being-anyval)

Comment: Thanks, but the provided Links does not tell me why it is the way is is. I do not want to check a primitive type, I just want to know, why AnyVal can not be used ? What is the background ? What is the rule behind this behavior ?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood Sorry, I missed the point. I cannot undo my close vote, but here comes an answer for your question.

Comment: [Some information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335319/what-are-the-relationships-between-any-anyval-anyref-object-and-how-do-they-m) to Any, AnyVal, AnyRef etc.

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. One is asking how to do it, the other (this one) is asking why it is not possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AnyVal` does not exist anymore at runtime. Only at compile-time. In other words, it's just a compiler "trick" to consider the JVM primitives as first-class objects.

However, the `isInstanceOf` method is executed at runtime, so it cannot work. Hence the compiler error.

Comment: I am not sure if this is ugly or nice.

Comment: Well, `isInstanceOf` is considered as ugly in Scala ;-) You should rely on the type system to get that kind of information at compile time.

Comment: I'm probably being very thick, but I don't understand the logic of this answer. You don't in general disallow boolean methods just because the answer is always "false". And `1.isInstanceOf[Int]` works fine... And the answers to the linked "duplicate" show that such a method is possible at runtime.

Comment: The accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416658/how-to-test-a-value-on-being-anyval relies on implicit evidence, which is also resolved at compile time.

Comment: I just tried to `javap` on `1.isInstanceOf[Int]`. It relies on boxing and checks at runtime if the boxed 1, is an instance of `java.lang.Integer`.