# Irregularities in the Scala class hierarchy

Tags: scala

Scala superimposes a very elegant class hierarchy over Java's type system, balooning out from Any at the top, into AnyRef and AnyVal to cover Java's Objects and primitives respectively, then finally converging, collapsing the reference types onto Null and all types onto Nothing. As I understand it, Nothing is a subtype of everything; Null a subtype of all subtypes of AnyRef/java.lang.Object. [ see http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128 ]

However, there seem to be a few irregularities, a few places where it does not work to simply think of all Scala types as elements of a seamless type hierarchy. I find this irksome, and want to understand the places where I might be surprised.

So far, I know of a few irregularities:

1) Although Null is a subtype of AnyRef, calling null.isInstanceOf[AnyRef] (or other subtypes of AnyRef) returns false. I suspect this was chosen to be consistent with the behavior of Java's instanceof operator.

2) Everything is covariant to Nothing, regardless of variance annotations. If I have a method that returns a type T that is not marked covariant, I can override that method to return type Nothing. **[NOTE: this claim is mistaken, see answers and comments below!]**

3) I can't apply isInstanceOf to the type AnyVal [ See [Why can AnyVal not be used in an isInstanceOf check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070859) and [How to test a value on being AnyVal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416658) ]

4) It is illegal to ask whether something isInstanceOf[Null], which is a perfectly coherent thing to ask (although not particularly necessary, since "myVar == null" would give the same answer)

Are there other examples of irregularities or special cases in Scala's type hierarchy? I feel like these are worth learning and understanding to avoid unwelcome surprises.

Comment: 2) isn't true. The first sentence is not supported by the second. Try `trait T[A]; case class C[A]() extends T[A]; val l:T[String] = C[Nothing]()`. It won't work due to invariance. If you change it to `+A` it does work.

Comment: null.isInstanceOf[Null] is false, because null is not an instance.

Comment: Kim -- Yeah. I clearly messed up the description of (2). I saw some weirdness that I wrongly took to be a variance issue. It's not. Still, there is some weird behavior I don't get, see my comment to axel22's response below.

Comment: Ricky -- why wouldn't we think of null as a singleton instance of the type Null? in every respect, that's what it seems to be. we define it away because we know that it doesn't imply an Object on the JVM's heap? seems like an implementation detail. because defining it as "not an instance" matches the behavior of instanceof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) `"A string is a subtype of AnyRef".isInstanceOf[AnyRef]` returns `true`. This is true for other subtypes of `AnyRef` as well, except for `Null`. The only irregularity there is done to be consistent with Java, as you said.

2) If `B` is a subtype of `A`, that is `B <: A`, then you can always override a method:

```
def foo: A = ...
```

to:

```
override def foo: B = ...
```

This is called refining the return type, and is always allowed. Since `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type (`Nothing <: A` for all `A`), you can always refine your return type to `Nothing` (e.g. by throwing an exception in the body of the method). This is a pretty regular property. The return type covariance is not directly related to [variance annotations on type parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129).

3) The other questions cover this nicely.

4) This is because the `Null` type does not exist in the Java runtime. I guess if you wanted to emulate this, you could create your own `instanceOf` method - you would first have to check if the argument is `null`, otherwise, do the normal `isInstanceOf` check.

There are other irregularities, yes. See for example: [If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749010/if-an-int-cant-be-null-what-does-null-asinstanceofint-mean/10750800#10750800)

Arrays are another example, where you may pay the uniformity of generic arrays with boxing/unboxing or `instanceof` checks at runtime. The `new Array[Any]` is translated into an object array - storing an integer into the array will result in boxing it. Whenever you use an `Array[T]`, where `T` has no upper bound, the array will be patterned matched against the correct runtime array type every time you index an element.

To better understand how you might be surprised it's useful to think in terms of how these constructs are translated to the JVM where there is a notion of primitive and reference types, boxing/unboxing and different array classes.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very helpful answer. The null.asInstanceOf[Int] boxing/unboxing looks like a ripe vein of confusing behavior to understand. Re (2), here's what seems strange. Define "class Foo[T]( arg : T ) { def echo : T = arg }" then try "class Baz[Object]( arg : Object ) extends Foo[Object](arg) {override def echo : String = "Hello" }". Won't compile. Change override type from String to Nothing (and implement by throwing an error), then everything's cool.

Comment: That won't compile because you didn't extend `Foo` with a concrete type `Object`. Instead, you're introducing a type parameter called `Object` on `Baz` and passing that along to the superclass `Foo`. This `Object` has nothing to do with `java.lang.Object`, it is just an arbitrary type and you might as well have called it `T`. Naturally, `String` is not a subtype of an arbitrary type `T`, so you cannot override `echo` this way. The solution is to remove the `[Object]` after `Baz` - this is what you intended.

Comment: axel22 -- thanks! that does explain the behavior that confused me, and very understandably.